# How to connect as an user under PDB, using Oracle SQL Developer, to generate ERD for those table stored in PDB

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Using Oracle XE 18c Home, when login in *sqlplus* like `/ as sysdba` I would be land on CDB$ROOT, and can't retrieve tables created with user001 that parked under XEPDB1, same to SQL Developer, but...

in order to view those table in *sqlplus*, I could have these

```
/ as sysdba
connect user001/user001@localhost/xepdb1
```

then I can retrieve my data.

Now come into SQL Developer, even though I connect successfully as user001 using query (initially connect as sysdba), the tables still do not appear at database explorer, no way for me to create ERD.

Comment: I can connect as SYS to my PDB (not the seed, not the CDB), and I can easily browse schemas/objects to import to my Modeler design.

Answer (score 0):

```
<username>/<password>@<hostname>:<port_number>/<servicename>
sysdba/abc123@127.0.0.1:1521/xepdb1
```

hence when setting up connection, use the default service name come along with the default pluggable db, both named as **XEPDB1**, so no need to create a custom one to connect a certain db. If want to create custom service for any db except PDB$SEED, pls refer to this site that helped me:
https://dbaliveblog.wordpress.com/establish-connections-to-cdbs-and-pdbs/

When it's all about no clarification from lecturer nor practical slides nor I know the fastest way to solve it, posting here is just to help students